# How to show full document path in Open Office title bar?

Tags: openoffice

How can I automatically show the FULL PATH of the currently loaded document (not just only the file name) in the title bar of Apache Open Office 4, e.g. OO-Writer?

Comment: There's an [bugzilla entry](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=105909) on this - voting it up may increase probability that it will get fixed.

Comment: What is your name kid

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a feature that has not been implemented yet into OO. You could achieve a similar result by displaying the URL in one of the toolbars, instead of the titlebar. Go to View > Toolbars > Customize. Add the "Load URL" option to the toolbar of your choice.

Or, if you feel comfortable with macros, you could create one and then make it run on the "open document' event. Create and save the macro, go again to the Customize dialog and under Events, select Open document, then click Assign macro. The macro itself should be something like this:

```
Sub
FilePath
thisDoc = ThisComponent
If thisDoc.hasLocation then
MsgBox ConvertFromURL(thisDoc.Url)
Else   
MsgBox "Not saved"
EndIf 
EndSub
```

Comment: There is no Load URL anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not how to display the path somewhere but specifically in the window title. This not only affords the best utilization of display space but also makes the location readable in a thumbnail. It can only be done by macro bound to Open Document (for OO/LO, not for each document).

```
Sub OnOpenDoc
Dim frame as object
frame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
frame.SetTitle(ConvertFromURL(ThisComponent.URL))
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This feature has always been built into Open Office and its predecessors. It's so essential that I just can't for the life of me understand why it's not in the default view. I have to re-figure it out every time I put OO on a new machine, and it takes an hour because they bury it so deep.  Here you go:
Tools menu> Customize >Toolbars tab > Standard Toolbar > Toolbar Content >
Now are you ready?-drumroll please: Put a check in front of the top item, LOAD URL You're welcome.